# curl ibm bluemix .wav file cannot be found anywhere

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud

quick question, I'm testing the api of IBM bluemix using curl and I just took there basic command but the question might be stupid, but where can I find the .wav file that has been transmitted?
here is the command I ran:
 curl -X POST -u "xxxxxxx":"xxxxxxx" \

> --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
>   --header "Accept: audio/wav" \
>   --data "{\"text\":\"hello world\"}" \
>   --output hello_world.wav \
>   "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api"

and this is what I got after running this:
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   238    0   216  100    22    175     17  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   175

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You told it where to place the file using `--output`. It should be in `hello_world.wav`